# How can I find the address of this web downloadable .csv file?

Tags: python, html, csv

If I go to this website:

https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#ed-visits

and click the "download" button (on the right), a .csv file is downloaded.

I can't find the address of that csv file, so that I could fetch it automatically with pd.read_csv(). I had a snoop around the web inspector thing, but I don't really know what I'm doing, and nothing jumped out at me as being the obvious answer. I've also looked around various other sites to try to find an API that gives me access to this data, bat there doesn't appear to be such thing.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to open your web inspector and go to the "Network"-Tab and then reload the page. You are going to see, that there's never a csv actually being loaded.
Also the export button doesn't link to any file. Rather it has some javascript binding, that exports the existing data in your client (the browser) as a csv to your filesystem. In other words: There isn't an address for that file. Its being created in your browser.

So even better, you can read the json directly. Just find the correct data in the Network-Tab, I think it might be this: https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData?id=ed_trend_data

So instead you could directly read the json:
`pd.read_json('https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData?id=ed_trend_data')` and then filter for the data that you need.